# C# | histogram of 8 bits grey level tif image

Tags: image, image-processing, histogram, tiff, grayscale

I have an image 8 bit grey Level tif image with 72dpi. I want to load this image using C# and get the histogram as an array.

If opening the image in IrfanView the histogram Looks fine (see image).
After loading the image with different approaches (Bitmap class, using streams, GetPixel...) the histogram and the data looks like clustered (see image).

Histograms of original and loaded images:

[image: img]

The problem is that I didn't found a way to load the image from a file path without loosing the image information.

I think the analysis of the single pixels and the array is not the issue. The issue really is to load the data without loosing the greylevel Information.

If you have Solutions please post all needed Information including needed assemblys etc.

Comment: open the image in C# and then save it. If the saved image has distorted histogram in IrfanView too then you are right and you got bad loader. If not then your pixel access or histogram computation/rendering is wrong

Comment: That looks like a histogram with just 16 bins, so it either corresponds to a 4-bit image, or the histogramming function has defaulted to just using 16 bins - maybe there is an option to use 256 bins with the histogram?

Comment: Thanks for your Response! Spektre: Yes, it's the bad loader. Histogram Comes from the Image saved with the c# code. Do you know (other) Options? Mark: It#s not an histogram issue. Used the same Settings for both Images and also checked the code (single Pixels). After loading the data the Image is really shrinked to 16 greylevel.